# Could animals/plants survive off of coolant instead of water?

Tags: biology, fauna, biochemistry, water

Say there was a source of water that animals and plants alike were surviving in, a sort of desert oasis situation, here we have Fred, he is an animal who lives off of this body of water. Buts let's say this body of water happened to be a body of coolant, a mixture of water and methanol, specifically 50-60% methanol:40-50% water, which would make the water's freezing point somewhere between -54 and -71 Celcius. Ignoring the issue of methanol being flammable, is it possible for animals like Fred here could adapt to use the water from this oasis?

Edit: *These animals would have evolved from regular Earth animals.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Earthly terrestrial life, methanol is a poisonous intoxicant.

It's used as a denaturing agent in ethanol (to make it too toxic to get drunk on), usually combined with a warning dye and/or bitter flavoring (Bitrex is often used, sometimes called the bitterest substance known).

For an animal to survive drinking water with this level of methanol contamination, then, it would need a way to either filter the methanol before it can be absorbed and metabolized, evaporate it off the water in a similar time frame, or a biochemistry that tolerates methanol rather better than real world mammals tolerate ethanol (that's roundly like 100 proof liquor -- you'd die pretty shortly if you drank only 100 proof vodka without access to actual water).

Let's go for both evaporation and filtration. Fred has a dense (but short) coat of hair, similar to that of Earthly seals (it keeps him warm, too, both in the frigid lake and when on shore) and doesn't actually drink at all.  Instead, he periodically bathes in the lake, allowing his coat to absorb significant quantities of the coolant, and then waits.  Skin glands similar to human sweat glands, but operating in reverse, selectively absorb the water even as the methanol evaporates off (this would be a slow process, though the small amount of escaping body heat would accelerate it).  This not only provides Fred with water for his metabolism, the higher evaporation rate of the methanol gives much more efficient cooling than sweating would, giving Fred a much wider temperature comfort range than most animals his size.

Comment: The only problem that I have with filtering the methanol is that the lake made of coolant is because I want to design a "cold oasis" where the water is liquid at the very low temperatures(antarctic temperatures, so <-40C). I chose methanol because, in my google searches, it lowered the freezing point of water the most(https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/methanol-water-d_987.html), and is also naturally produced by plants. So I feel like the animal, since instead of coolant would be using regular water, would freeze to death in the very low temperatures.

Comment: A seal's coat lets it swim comfortably in sea water below the freezing point of fresh water, and prevents skin from freezing when the animal emerges onto an ice floe.  Add a layer of subcutaneous blubber and tailor the coat (perhaps as an over- and under-coat like that of a polar bear) to hold the water and you have an animal that can survive deeply sub-freezing temperature even with wet fur.

Comment: And also wold be slowly taking away the water from the lake and simultaneously making the lake more toxic and eventually converting it to a lake of just boring ol' methanol

Comment: One must presume there's a source of water -- at least ice, which will dissolve well below its freezing point -- to keep the lake diluted...

Comment: Also worthy of note, evaporation rate of even methanol at that temperature is quite slow, so this would be mainly an osmotic filtering process (but would also potentially give Fred a HUGE comfort range, in terms of temperature).

Comment: Yes, the temperatures of this lake would be below the mixtures flash point

Comment: How would plants survive?

Comment: Seems like a separate question...

Comment: Ah._Okay. _________

Comment: Underscore is because comments require 15 characters

Answer (score 2):

If the animal is adapted to fit into such an environment, sure.

There are species which survive by breathing H2S which is lethal for humans in concentrations above 500 ppm, there are species which feast on ethylic alcohol which we use as disinfectant, there are species living in water so salty that brine is a refreshing lemonade in comparison, why should a mixture of water and methanol be any different?

To humans [methanol is toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol#Toxicity):

> Methanol is toxic by two mechanisms. First, methanol can be fatal due to effects on the central nervous system, acting as a central nervous system depressant in the same manner as ethanol poisoning. Second, in a process of toxication, it is metabolised to formic acid (which is present as the formate ion) via formaldehyde in a process initiated by the enzyme alcohol dehydrogenase in the liver. Methanol is converted to formaldehyde via alcohol dehydrogenase (ADH) and formaldehyde is converted to formic acid (formate) via aldehyde dehydrogenase (ALDH). The conversion to formate via ALDH proceeds completely, with no detectable formaldehyde remaining. Formate is toxic because it inhibits mitochondrial cytochrome c oxidase, causing hypoxia at the cellular level, and metabolic acidosis, among a variety of other metabolic disturbances.

What the animal need is either a biochemistry to which methanol brings no damage or a biochemistry which can actively use methanol.